# Can I use JQuery "this" with a descendant selector?

Tags: jquery

As I understand it, the following code will select any .my_class elements from within the #my_id element, regardless of whether they are a child, grandchild etc.

```
$("#my_id .my_class")
```

What I am trying to do is the same thing but to replace the #my_id with "this".  I have tried the following but must be doing it wrong.

```
 $(this, ".my_class")
```

Any help much appreciated.

*** EDIT ***

I realise this question has been answered already but was unable to find the question when I searched and I feel that the existing question isn't asked in a way that I would have understood exactly what they wanted to achieve.

Comment: you can use $(this).find(".my_class")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is close to the solution. The arguments should just be in reverse order:

```
$(".my_class", this)
```

So `this` is the `context` for the `selector` to be applied to -- [`jQuery(selector [, context])`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1).

---

You can also use [`jQuery(element)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-element) with [`.find(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/find/#find-selector), which the above [will ultimately use anyways](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context).

```
$(this).find(".my_class");
```

Comment: Thank you, so frustrating how close I was.

Answer (score 3):

To correct your attempt, reverse the arguments:

```
$('.my_class', this)...
```

Or use find:

```
$(this).find('.my_class')...
```